# IOS APP hangs and crashes after 2 seconds

Tags: react-native, crash, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I am getting this error and it is showing me main.js in the xcode and app got stuck,

I am using Firebase Analytics and performance.

If i remove performance or Analytics one of them app is working. Didn't able to find anything for this. Please check and provide me solution for this.

@react-native-firebase/perf creating issue didn't able to get why..
Tried many solutions but not able to find issue for this.
Error:

> Thread 1:
> "-[fir_BEE71E0E-B366-4996-A27B-D401B6DF700B_GULNetworkURLSession
> _flex_swizzle_a0c22ca7_URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001d98000"

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue?